# 110V Y connected supply with switch

Tags: switches, identification, terminology

I have two high-draw machines that I want to use on a single 110 V, 20 A outlet. I have a setup like this for a similar issue on 220 V:

[image]

I would like a setup like this on 110 V, so that I can manually switch between the two machines without worrying that both would draw from the circuit simultaneously.

Unfortunately, I don't know what the terminology is to search for on the internet. I assume this exists, but I need to know what to search for.

Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: "I have two high draw machines that I want to use on a single 110V 20A outlet." "Unfortunately, I don't know what the terminology is to search for on the internet. I assume this exists, but I need to know what to search for."   Seems perfectly on-topic for me.  The fellow is trying to learn the proper terminology, not requesting buying advice.

Comment: FYI, this likely better belongs on the Home Improvement Stack Exchange. Keywords can be found by looking up the existing device. You probably want a 5-20P type. Offhand, I don't see such an example, though.

Comment: I haven't seen such a thing (but I haven't looked for one either...)  It should be easy to build one from parts available from your favourite home improvement store.